# Adding Service Reference in VS 2012 over SSL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ssl, service-reference

How to create a service reference in VS 2012 over SSL
ie service is available @ ![https:\theprovider.com\someservice.asmx]

When i tried to add the the service link in VS 2012 i'm getting the following error

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Pls comment

Comment: Have  to tried to Fiddler to check the response header? By looking at the error, it seems the service is not available over SSL. Try to hit the link in browser.

Comment: Btw, your URL should be `https://theprovider.com/someservice.asmx`

Comment: https://theprovider.com/someservice.asmx is example link the original link is different is is visible if accessed thru internet explorer